# Laravel 5 Check queue:work run on windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-queue

I send email on my script with laravel queue.
I need to run  `php artisan queue:work` on my script for run laravel queue.
I want to monitor if this `php artisan queue:work` failed, I run again. My solution is command like this on corn job

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
     protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
     {
              if(check queue failed)
              $schedule->command("php artisan queue:work")->cron("* * * * *");
     }
}
```

I have two question
1- what condition I should use instead of `check queue failed`
2- Is there any better solution?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, not yet.....

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did, following some tutorials online; it works fine and is not creating more instances

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --queue=high,low --tries=3')
    ->everyMinute()
    ->withoutOverlapping();
```

The important part is `->withoutOverlapping()`, which will execute the command again if it is not running anymore. I still have to find a way to test what happens if it hangs, hopefully someone else can improve this answer